# Property missing in cosmos mongodb property after insertion

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a .Net Core 2.1 Web API Which Inserts a Record into MongoDB(Azure CosmosDB Mongo Variant) with multiple properties like Id, Status, DateTime and other Objects.
Later I have added another Property named Title and now when I hit the API it inserts the Record but it this newly added 'Title' Property is not added to the Collection.

- While Debugging, I have checked the property is available just before it is inserted.
- I added a property with a new name still it didn't work.
- If I am updating an existing record with the 'Title' property value then the Title property is getting added.
- If I am inserting new record Title property is missing
- If I check from Mongo Compass, Just when I finish API and refresh the collection I find the Record inserted with the Title property populated but once I refresh again then Title property is missing.

I suspect it is because of the DLL reference that is cached somewhere. I have tried removing all the references related to that DLL and refreshed them (even that did not work)

I am using MongoDB Driver 2.8.0

Comment: it would be nearly impossible to find the issue without seeing your code imho...